# Why can no prime number appear as the length of a hypotenuse in more than one Pythagorean triangle?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, pythagorean-triples

Why is it that no prime number can appear as the length of a hypotenuse in more than one Pythagorean triangle? In other words, could any of you give me a algebraic proof for the following?

> Given prime number $p$, and Pythagorean triples $(a,b,p)$ and $(c,d,p)$ where $a<b<p$ and $c<d<p$, then $b=d$.

Please also have a look at the deeper question:
[Is there any formula to calculate the number of different Pythagorean triangle with a hypotenuse length $n$, using its prime decomposition?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1820448/346836)

Comment: The [fact that such a prime $p$ must satisfy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) $$p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$$ may be helpful.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee no... since we already know that... a prime must be of the form of $p=4k+1$ to appear as a hypotenuse... but the question is why this number appear just in one Pythagorean triple?

Comment: look... $25$ appears in two Pythagorean triple $(15,20,25)$ and $(7,24,25)$ but $29$ appear in just one triple...

Comment: An elementary detailed proof is rather lengthy.  Please see the uniqueness part of [this proof.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fermat's_Two_Squares_Theorem) The proof is more pleasant and more informative if we can use properties of Gaussian integers.

Comment: David Cox has quite a good exposition of the elementary method of descent required to prove these sorts of facts in his book Primes of the form x^2 + ny^2.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I want to take my question one level deeper... so I think it worth to ask as another question... I wish you friends give me some hints on that question too...

Comment: @BenjaminGadoua I will wait for you too...

Comment: We give a brief version of the Gaussian integer approach.  By the usual representation theorem, the odd prime $p$ is a hypotenuse iff $p=s^2+t^2=(s+ti)(s-ti)$. The two factors are Gaussian primes, so by unique factorization  $(u+vi)(u-vi)=p$ only if $u+iv$ is a unit times $s\pm ti$.

Comment: For any primitive Pythagorean triple, $B+C=x^2,x\in\mathbb{N}$. There can be only one number $B$ smaller than $C$ that, when added to $C$, yields a perfect square. $$2mn+(m^2+n^2)\quad =m^2+2mn+n^2\quad =(m+n)^2$$

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This goes back to Euler, who showed that if there are two ways of writing an odd integer $N$ as the sum of two squares, then $N$ is composite. There is a 2009 article on this by Brillhart. Let me try to find a link.

http://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/american-mathematical-monthly/american-mathematical-monthly-december-2009

And if one note that in a primitive triple the hypotenuse is of the form $(u^2+v^2)$, and the legs are of the form $(u^2-v^2)$ and $(2uv)$. So by euler if the hypotenuse is prime it couldn't be written in different ways.

[image]

Comment: This http://www.jstor.org/stable/40391253 ?

Comment: Here is a better scan, from JSTOR: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DDymG.gif

Comment: @lhf good. I made a jpeg of the relevant page and pasted that in. He also has a 2016 article that allows indefinite quadratic forms, although in that case more care is needed about what is meant by distinct representations.

Comment: when a number is hypotenuse... its square is going to written as sum of squares... so it is of course composite then... it is $p^2$ not $p$...

Comment: @Omid, the standard construction for primitive Pythagorean triangles has the hypoteneuse as $r^2 + s^2;$ the triple is $(r^2 - s^2, 2rs, r^2 + s^2),$ with your prime $p = r^2 + s^2$ All integer triples $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ with $\gcd(x,y,z) = 1$ occur as the given recipe, with $\gcd(r,s) = 1$ but not both odd.

Comment: @WillJagy oh... yes... if it's prime... it's primitive... ;) ☺

Comment: @WillJagy I want to take my question one level deeper... so I think it worth to ask as another question... I wish you friends give me some hints on that question too...

Comment: @lhf I waiting for your hints too...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1820448/346836

Answer (score 14):

As noted in the comments and the accepted answer, this comes down to the fact that if a prime $p$ can be written as a sum of two squares, then the representation is unique up to switching and or negating the factors. A fancier explanation for this is the fact that $\mathbb Z[i]$ is a principal ideal domain and its unit group is $\{\pm1,\pm i\}$. (Of course, proving that $\mathbb Z[i]$ is a PID requires some sort of argument like that in the scanned note, but this is a more modern way to think about it.) Once one knows it's a PID, then suppose that $p=u^2+v^2$. Then $p=(u+iv)(u-iv)$, and the fact that $u+iv$ and $u-iv$ have norm $p$ shows that they cannot factor further in $\mathbb Z[i]$. Hence they are irreducible (i.e., they generate prime ideals). So the *unique* factorization of the ideal $p\mathbb Z[i]$ is as the product of the prime ideals $(u+iv)\mathbb Z[i]$ and $(u-iv)\mathbb Z[i]$. So $u$ and $v$ are unique, up to switching them or replacing them by their negatives, which corresponds to multiplying $u+iv$ by each of the four units in $\mathbb Z[i]$.

Comment: very interesting!

Answer (score 1):

If a Pythagorean triple is primitive, $B+C$ is a perfect square as shown by

$$2mn+(m^2+n^2)\quad=\quad m^2+2mn+nn^2\quad=\quad(m+n)^2$$

If $C$ is prime,  then only one smaller value $(B)$ can add to it to make a perfect square.   Given $C\&B$, there can be only a one $A$ to make a Pythagorean triple.